# How to create a spilling two colors gradient along a shape/stroke? I'd like to recreate one of these examples

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient

I'd like to recreate one of these examples. Is it possible to do this with Adobe Illustrator? Another software?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These aren't really gradients.  You could do something similar by creating a custom Art Brush.

An example

[image]Click to enlarge

If you want the edges to fade out, draw a black shape and blur it, set Opacity to "Multiply" mode, use a clipping mask to crop everything.

An example

[image]

Comment: Great idea! Thanks, Billy Kerr

Comment: Do you think there's a way to turn these serifs to another side (when between two shapes the blend tool is activated) [link](https://imgur.com/a/mVma0Nk)
 [link](https://imgur.com/txEt3JN)

Comment: @Roman - I'm not sure how you ended up with these pointing in the wrong direction TBH.  You should be able to [apply the brush](https://imgur.com/EZyNKX9) to your blend.

Comment: Might need to just reverse path directions.

Comment: @Scott - possibly, but how did the paths get reversed in the first place? A simple blend doesn't usually reverse path directions of the parts inside the blend.

Comment: Could be a number of ways.. copying the first circle, mistaken rotation, etc. Ai tends to swap path direction while *working* fairly easily. I admit, it's odd looking... and I'm not 100% certain *why* merely the blend iterations are reversed. Could be the blend was created *after* applying the brush. Blend, then apply brush perhaps.